# Bulk updating records with peewee FlaskDb

Tags: peewee

I'm wanting to update hundreds (or even thousands) of records at a time with Peewee FlaskDb (which is in an App Factory).

Referencing the Peewee documentation, I have `bulk_update` working well (and it is very fast compared to other methods), but it fails when using batches.

For example, `Ticket.bulk_update(selected_tickets, fields=[Ticket.customer])` works great, but when I use the following code to update in batches I receive the following error.

***code***

```
    with db.atomic():
        Ticket.bulk_update(selected_tickets, fields=[Ticket.customer], batch=50)
```

***error***

```
    AttributeError: 'FlaskDB' object has no attribute 'atomic'
```

What is the recommended way of updating records in bulk with FlaskDB? Does FlaskDB support atomic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access peewee.Database methods on the FlaskDB wrapper class. Those methods do not exist, you need to refer to the underlying Peewee database:

```
# Here we assume db is a FlaskDB() instance:
peewee_db = db.database

with peewee_db.atomic():
    ...
```